# I'm plotting vectors with pyplot.arrows. Is there a proper way to connect ends of vectors with dashed lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, vector

I'm plotting several vectors using pyplot arrows like this:

```
M = np.array([[Vx, Vy], [Vx, 0], [0, Vy], [ax, ay], [ax, 0], [0, ay],
              [-Vx + ax, -Vy + ay],
              ])
rows, cols = M.T.shape

colors = ['b', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'g']
labels = ['V, at', 'Vx', 'Vy', 'a', 'ax', 'ay', 'an']

for i, l in enumerate(range(0, cols)):
    plt.axes().arrow(X, Y, M[i, 0], M[i, 1], head_width=0.5, head_length=0.5, color=colors[i])
    plt.text(X + M[i, 0] - 0.7, Y + M[i, 1] + 0.7, s=labels[i],
             bbox={'facecolor': str(colors[i]), 'alpha': 0.5})
```

[image: Looks like this]

I want to connect the ends of vectors with dashed lines to show that some vectors are actually the summary of  other two:

[image: Desired way]

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
x1, y1 = [Vx + 1, Vx + 1], [-Vy + 2, Y]
x2, y2 = [Vx + 1, X], [-Vy + 2, -Vy + 2]
plt.plot(x1, y1, '--', color='c')
plt.plot(x2, y2, '--', color='c')
x3, y3 = [X, ax + 1], [Y + ay, Y + ay]
x4, y4 = [ax + 1, ax + 1], [Y + ay, Y]
plt.plot(x3, y3, '--', color='m')
plt.plot(x4, y4, '--', color='m')
x5, y5 = [-Vx + ax - 0.5, ax + 1], [-Y - Vy - ay - 0.5, Y + ay]
x6, y6 = [-Vx - ax, ax + 1], [-Vy - ay, Y + ay]
plt.plot(x5, y5, '--', color='y')
plt.plot(x6, y6, '--', color='y')
```

But lines getting kinda wrong (pic below) and I also have to add numbers like 0.5, 1, etc. to make it look decent. This way, if I change the vectors coordinates values, the lines would be shown incorrectly

[image: How it looks]

So is there a better way to connect the vectors with dashed lines? So if I change coordinates dashed lines would still be drawn correctly?
**Vectors coordinates values I used in this example:**

```
X = 1
Y = 8.2
Vx = 5.4
Vy = -3.1
V = 6.3
ax = 2.2
ay = -8.8
a = 9.1
at = 6.3
an = 6.6
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that your arrowheads does not stop (have their tip) at the correct point/position? In that case, check out this other SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233341/

Comment: @Wololo it seems like it's not only about arrows tips, but coordinates and lines lenght. If I remove all these 0.5, 1, etc. numbers I get this https://imgur.com/rZ1y9wo and as you can see I still didn't manage to make the last yellow line correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Basically I was just putting coordinates the wrong way. Here's the correct code:

```
x1, y1 = [X + Vx, X + Vx], [Y + Vy, Y]
x2, y2 = [X + Vx, X], [Y + Vy, Y + Vy]
plt.plot(x1, y1, '--', color='c')
plt.plot(x2, y2, '--', color='c')
x3, y3 = [X, X + ax], [Y + ay, Y + ay]
x4, y4 = [X + ax, X + ax], [Y + ay, Y]
plt.plot(x3, y3, '--', color='m')
plt.plot(x4, y4, '--', color='m')
x5, y5 = [X + ax - Vx, X + ax], [Y + ay - Vy, Y + ay]
x6, y6 = [X + Vx, X + ax], [Y + Vy, Y + ay]
plt.plot(x5, y5, '--', color='y')
plt.plot(x6, y6, '--', color='y')
```

[image]